# If a page is not linked to the main website, can search engines find it?

Tags: web, search-engine

I want to put a secret page in my website (www.mywebsite.com). The page URL is "www.mywebsite.com/mysecretpage".

If there is no clickable link to this secret page in the home page (www.mywebsite.com), can search engines still find it?

Comment: If there's a link *anywhere*, potentially yes. It's not just the front page which needs to have no link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hide from a web crawler: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

A web crawler collects links, and looks them up. So if your not linking to the site, and no one else is, the site won't be found on any search engine.

But you can't be sure, that someone looking for your page won't find it. If you want secret data, you should use a script of some kind, to grant access to those, who shall get access.

Here is a more useful link : http://www.seomoz.org/blog/12-ways-to-keep-your-content-hidden-from-the-search-engines

Answer (score 1):

No. A web spider crawls based on links from previous pages. If no page is linking it, search engine wouldn't be able to find it.